# How to use ES6 computed property names in node / iojs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

I am trying to write a tool that takes a CSV and dynamically generates a definition based on the header row?

For example, a CSV with:

```
Title(STRING), Description(TEXT)
Title Example, Description Example
...
```

the Sequelize [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#definition) specify, for example:

```
var Entry = sequelize.define('Entry', {
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
  description: Sequelize.TEXT
})
```

How could I write this definition so that it could be dynamically defined - so that `title` and the data type `Sequelize.STRING` could be dynamically generated based on the CSV header row?

---

**EDIT**

Ok, after some research, I think the obvious question is "How to use variable names as dynamic key names in object literal" and has been answered several times.

As a result, it is simple to write this in bracket notation so:

```
var definitionObj = {}
definitionObj['title'] = sequelize.STRING;
definitionObj['description'] = sequelize.TEXT;

var Entry = sequelize.define('Entry', definitionObj);
```

However, then my question now is **how do I use ES6 [Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) in node**? I'm using node 0.12.2 which I thought had ES6 support, and even with the `--harmony` flag, this simple code fails:

```
var Entry = sequelize.define('Entry', {
  ['title']: Sequelize.STRING,
  ['description']: Sequelize.TEXT
});
```

with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

Is the only option really to go to with [io.js](http://iojs.org)?

**EDIT 2**

Actually this syntax still fails even with iojs, so I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: Here is the support for the feature you're trying to use: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#object_literal_extensions_computed_properties.  Neither node nor io currently support it.

Comment: Also, you don't seem to need any computed property names here, as all of your object definitions are equivalent (and use static `title` and `description` names)?!

Comment: @NoahFreitas ah I see, so I'm not completely crazy then. Do you happen to know what this is referred to on the list?

Comment: @bergi sorry that was just for the example, in the actual use I want to use dynamic names as mentioned in the beginning (pulling header names from a CSV).

Comment: Can you please show how you pull the header names from the CSV?

Comment: @NoahFreitas also perhaps you want to make that as an answer and I can accept it

Comment: @Bergi I'm parsing the CSV with node-csv and just pulling the first row

Comment: I'd highly recommend that you check out [babel](http://babeljs.io)

Comment: with babel I've managed to get it running with computed properties :) (although perhaps a bit overkill as bracket syntax is working in this case without the overhead of a precompiler, but good to know)

Comment: It is now supported since NodeJS 4.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ECMAScript 6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) shows that neither Node nor io.js currently have support for computed properties.  The data is under [object literal extensions](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#object_literal_extensions) > [computed properties](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#object_literal_extensions_computed_properties).

Comment: It is now supported since NodeJS 4.x.

Answer (score 6):

In current **Node** release **> 4.x** you have some support for ES6. Status can be found in documentation:
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/

What you are looking for is called

> Computed (dynamic) property names

and it is fully supported now. Details can be found here: https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals

Usage:

```
var obj = {
    // Computed (dynamic) property names
    [ 'prop_' + (() => 42)() ]: 42
};
```

Will produce object: {prop_42: 42}

Answer (score 1):

Now can use it in iojs v3.0

**Changelog** https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-notable-changes